# Time data transformation in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am new to Grafana.

I have the below timeseries data. I am using Grafana 10.2

```
Time                | Power Value

19-11-2023 00:05:00 | 200

19-11-2023 00:10:00 | 210

.

.

19-11-2023 23:55:00 | 230
```

I need to transform this to the below

```
StartTime           | StartPower | EndTime            |EndPower|Power used
19-11-2023 00:05:00 | 200        |19-11-2023 23:55:00 |230     |30 (230-200)
```

Could you please help to achieve this ? I tried to use Groupby options, but no success there as yet

Comment: I don't think this can be (easily) done in Grafana. If it's possible - consider extracting data in already aggregated state from your data source if possible.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use time series panel, and simply add legend with values like min, max and delta.